# Capture search engine keywords in php

Tags: php, seo, keyword

In awstats I get a table with all the key words and phrases used to find my website.  I would like to capture this myself however each search engine url is in a different format.  When google is the referer I can use the variable q from the querystring as the search term (e.g. google.com?q=my+keywords) however another search engine may have the format searchengine.com?search=my+keywords

Is there a generic way of identifying search keywords?  Or am I going to have to create a regex/filter for each search engine?

Comment: Edited to include the 'php' tag, since it was specifically included in the question-title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to just grab the referring URL (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) and parse out the keywords in it.

For example, check out this Google URL (searching for "stack overflow"):

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stack+overflow&aq=0&oq=stack+over&aqi=g10
```

The value of the `q` GET variable holds the keywords delimited by + signs.

Comment: Microsoft's 'Bing' does the same thing, as does ask.com; Yahoo uses the 'p' GET variable. Whereas Wolfram Alpha "wasn't sure what to do with [my] input"...

Comment: @ricebowl: that's because wolfram alpha isn't a search engine, it is indeed a "computational knowledge engine".

Comment: @eyze; that was quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am having to add to it all the time, but here is a REGEX that should strip out the keywords from google, yahoo, bing, ask, and MSN (same as Bing). It leaves the + in between, but it should be a good place for you to start:

```
.*(\?p=|\?q=|&q=|\?s=)([a-zA-Z0-9 +]*)(&toggle=|&ie=utf-8|&FORM=|&aq=|&x=|&gwp).
```