# How to get Keywords used from a Search Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search-engine, keyword

I am using C# asp.NET and I have searched the internet up and down trying to find a solution to this problem. In google analytics they have the keywords used by search engines so there must be a way to do it. thanks

Comment: If you have the data in Google Analytics, why do you need to get it on the server side? Is there a deeper question here?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean determining the search keywords that led a user to your site?  This is done by analyzing the referrer URL.

```
string referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Most of them are pretty simple, but there are different patterns for different search engines.

Comment: Darn..I thought there was a different way to do this

Comment: Nope, that's it.  You should probably write or find a generic routine to parse a query string, then return a different parameter from the query string based on the value or pattern of `Request.UrlReferrer.Host`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349774/capture-search-engine-keywords-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I found out that besides implementing your own algorithm to extract keywords I can use google analytics to do this. Google has an api for their analytics software and this is what i have been using. The only thing that is difficult is if you have more then 10,000 pages you have to open an adwords account.

Comment: How are you doing this with the google API.  I went and read their documentation but couldn't see how to pull a single visits keyword with it.

Does anyone know of a keyword parsing subroutine in c#?

I want to grab the keyword a visitor used and then use it in my codebehind on each visit to track which keywords results in various actions.