# Capture search terms with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I've seen various articles and posts on how to use PHP tp grab the search term used to find a site. For example,

[Capture search engine keywords in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349774/capture-search-engine-keywords-in-php)

How can I also do this with Javascript / jQuery?

Ultimately, I want to grab the keywords and use them for an AJAX request that I already have written and working (for something else similar but different).

Note: This is a new area for me so type slow, spoon feed it, and if ya can, links to more details are always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer) to get the url of the previous page url like so:

```
console.log(document.referrer);
```

would output something like:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stack+overflow&aq=0&oq=stack+over&aqi=g10
```

to just feed to your ajax.

Comment: As of 8 October 2019. Browser does not return full URI they just return "https://www.google.com/" if you use google to search the website and same thing with Bing.

Answer (score 2):

Using the regex from the question you linked to, this function will return an array of keywords used to find the current page, or an empty array:

```
function parse_keywords(url){
    var matches = url.match(/.*(?:\?p=|\?q=|&q=|\?s=)([a-zA-Z0-9 +]*)(?:&toggle=|&ie=utf-8|&FORM=|&aq=|&x=|&gwp)/);
    return matches ? matches[1].split('+') : [];
}

console.log(parse_keywords(document.referrer)); // Get keywords from referrer
console.log(parse_keywords('http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stack+overflow&aq=0&oq=stack+over&aqi=g10')); // Or any given url
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: you can't.

> EDIT: Well, you can. My fault. See the `document.referrer` answer. My
>   last point is still valid, though.

Extended version: Javascript is running client-side while PHP is running on the web server. Hence, PHP has access to environment variables such as HTTP referer and may extract parts of it. In any case you need to deliver some information along with your website (e.g. hidden fields) which in turn may be processed via javascript.

Also, your ajax request is (you guess it) a call to a server-side script. So you might want to use the logic of that script in your website delivery script.